# Derivative of $\frac1{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Why is this not correct:
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}= (1-x)^{-1}
$$

now use chain-rule which gives: $(1-x)^{-2}$ times derivative of $(1-x)$ which is $-1$
so
$$
-1\cdot (1-x)^{-2}= \frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}
$$

why is this incorrect?

Because if I use quotient rule on $1/(1-x)$ I get
$$
\frac{0 \cdot (1-x) - 1\cdot -1}{(1-x)^2}= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.
$$

So why do I get with using chain rule on $(1-x)^{-1}$ a different answer?
$$
\frac{d}{dx} (1-x)^{-1}= \frac{d}{du} (u)^{-1} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (u),$$
 with $$u=1-x \Longrightarrow (u)^{-2}\cdot( -1)= \frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: It should be "which gives $(-1)\cdot(1-x)^{-2}\ldots$"

Answer (score 10):

Remember $\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$, so in the first case you should have 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(1-x)^{-1}=(-1)(1-x)^{-2}\left(\frac{d}{dx}(1-x)\right)=(-1)(1-x)^{-2}(-1)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac d{dx} (1-x)^{-1} = -1\cdot (1 - x)^{-2} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}(1-x)}_{\large =\,-1}$$

$$ = -1\cdot -1\cdot (1 - x)^{-2}= \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use graph to see the property of $ \dfrac{1}{(1-x)} $:
[image: Graph of 1/(1-x)]

As we can see, as $x$ is increasing, $y$ is always increasing. Which means the derivative of the function must always be $ \gt 0 $. And therefore $ \dfrac{-1}{(1-x)^2} $ is not good since it's always $ \le 0 $.

Meanwhile, when we derive it manually by using $ \dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} $ we will get  $ \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2} $, and it is always $ \gt 0 $. My point is, when in doubt, try to visualise it (or look at the graph) and it will help us to see which answer makes sense.